# How to avoid multi joins

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dimension

I have the following code. In order to get the cost_center, I have to do 2 joins - first on the combination of billing_area_id and facility_id and if no match, I have to join on just billing_area_id to get it. I want to design a dimension for cost_center that should satisfy this scenario such that only one time join should be enough. Please let me know if you have any ideas

```
select COALESCE(cs1.cost_center,cs2.cost_center) cost_center
from fact_invoice i
inner join dim_facility f on i.hospital_id = f.id 
left join lookup_billingarea_to_wd_costcenter cs1 on i.billing_area_id = cs1.billing_area_id and COALESCE (i.hospital_id,0) = cs1.facility_id
left join lookup_billingarea_to_wd_costcenter cs2 on i.billing_area_id = cs2.billing_area_id and (cs1.cost_center IS NULL and cs2.facility_id=0)
```

Added for clarification
I apologize for not providing the data. One billing_area_id can have multiple facility_id and a 0 record facility_id. But the challenge for me, there might be cases, where we dont get matching facility_id and in that case, we just need to take the record with 0 facility_id. For ex, please see below
Lets say we have

```
Billing_area_id Facility_id cost_center
1   0   abc
1   3   acd
2   0   abd
2   1   ghf
2   2   hgf
```

If I have the input of Billing_area_id = 1 and Facility_id = 2 (which the combination do not exist in the lookup table), then, I need to get "abc" as the cost centre

Comment: @SentalPL what makes you think laravel is used here?

Comment: @Phani so you have to do 2 joins (that's 3 actually, but..).. why is it a concern? Databases do joins all the time

Comment: @CaiusJard, I understand we can have multi joins, but I want to simplify not to get one value with 2 joins as this is being used in multiple places

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view that does the join, then use the view in your multiple places:

```
CREATE VIEW lookup_billingarea_to_wd_costcenter_with_default AS
SELECT 
  cs1.billing_area_id,
  cs1.facility_id,
  COALESCE(cs1.cost_center,cs2.cost_center) as cost_center
FROM
  lookup_billingarea_to_wd_costcenter cs1
  INNER JOIN lookup_billingarea_to_wd_costcenter cs2
  ON 
    cs1.billing_area_id = cs2.billing_area_id AND
    cs2.billing_area_id = 0
```

Note, you didn't post any example data for this so it's a bit of a guess that for every billing_area_id you have N facility_id that is non zero and also a row where facilityID is 0. If you don't have that, and sometimes there is no zero row, you'll need to left join cs2

You'd use it like:

```
select COALESCE(cs1.cost_center,cs2.cost_center) cost_center
from fact_invoice i
inner join dim_facility f on i.hospital_id = f.id 
inner join lookup_billingarea_to_wd_costcenter_with_default cs 
ON i.billing_area_id = cs.billing_area_id AND COALESCE(i.hospital_id, 0) = cs.facility_id
```

If there is ever a case where there isn't a cost center for these things, you'll need to left join the view